# Return generics class in Scala

Tags: scala

I don't have enough experience whith scala and I am trying to convert this java method to scala:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] preRootContextClassConfiguration() {
    return new Class[] { 
            DatabaseSourceConfig.class,
            DatabaseJpaConfig.class,
            JpaConfig.class,
            SpringDataJpaConfig.class,
            ServiceConfig.class,
        };
}
```

My problem is I don't know convert "

`Class<?>[]`

to scala.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Scala equivalent of Java's Class[] is Array[Class[_]]

Try:

```
override def preRootContextClassConfiguration() = Array(
  classOf[DatabaseSourceConfig],
  classOf[DatabaseJpaConfig],
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code should replace your java function.  A very nice feature of Scala is that you rarely have to declare your type in advance, the compiler will do the checking for you...

```
override def protected preRootContextClassConfiguration() = {
  Array(DatabaseSourceConfig.class, DatabaseJpaConfig.class, ...)
}
```